# SAPUI5 / OPENUI5 - Function on button won't work

Tags: javascript, sapui5

If you can see here the code I made it in SAP WEB Ide then I moved to an apache server to test due to CORs problems. I only want that Log In button to call the alert, but it is not even working.

Here I posted the JSBIN to make it easier to understand:
 https://jsbin.com/cejicaqobe/edit?html,output

```
   <Button text="Log In " width="100px" id="myButton" press="getLogin"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS Bin, the alert is not shown because you have not associated the view with the controller. The easiest way to do it is by passing a `controllerName` to the view specification in the XML:

```xml
 <mvc:View controllerName="sap.m.sample.NavContainer.C">
     <!-- the view's contents -->
 </mvc:View>
```

In the controller name, you have to pass the controller class name (you specified it in the `Controller.extend` call). The instantiation of the controller is done for you by the framework.

I forked your bin and made it to work here: https://jsbin.com/gesezuhasa/1/edit?html,output.

Alternatively, you can pass a controller instance to the [sap.ui.xmlview](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.xmlview) or sap.ui.view call. This means that you have to instantiate the controller first.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked! Sorry for my very beginner question.:How can I remove the script into a JS file? in UI5

Comment: You just have to move the whole `sap.ui.define` call inside a JS file, while respecting the [standard structure](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/003f755d46d34dd1bbce9ffe08c8d46a.html). You can find a very simple example here: [GitHub](https://github.com/serban-petrescu/non-dev-intro/tree/master/src/main/webapp). Basically in the `index.html` I am specifying that the artifacts of my namespace (`msg.demo`) can be found in the current folder (you can specify any path in there). That's how when I request the `msg.demo.Employee` controller it knows where to look.